# Как может в заголовочном файле отсутствовать объявление структуры?

Tags: c++, c, header, typedef, gtk3

Пытаюсь разобраться с примером для GTK-3.0
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s04.html#id-1.2.3.12.5

Что бы не лазить по различным хедерам - вывел отдельно прекомпилированный файл для exampleapp.c

Там очень много структур, определённых одни через другие. Я считал, что можно обычным поиском дойти до самого "корня", строчки где идет ссылка на встроенные типы данных, типа

```
typedef unsigned long long gsize;
```

Только вот по моему не получилось.
Есть строка

```
typedef struct _GData GData;
```

И на этом - всё!
Объявления структуры _GData в header файлах нет.
Вопрос. Как такое может быть? Ведь объявление должно быть обязательно? Или нет?

Всё компилируется и работает, только не могу понять, как...

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, я поторопился с вопросом... Только что узнал про существование "неполных типов" в Си.

> You can define structures, unions, and enumerations without listing
>   their members (or values, in the case of enumerations). Doing so
>   results in an incomplete type. You can’t declare variables of
>   incomplete types, but you can work with pointer to those types.

Вот так... Несколько дней пытался самостоятельно разобраться, но стоило "сдаться" и задать вопрос на форуме - так сразу ответ нашелся. Как будто подбросил кто.